# How to order data in ng-repeat with nested objects as JSON data in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

i want to show array of object's properties in angular view. following is the object

```
$scope._Json = {
    "foo": {
        "ItemDimension1": {
            "Item": "item1",
            "ItemIndex": 1,
            "SelectedItems": [{

                "Code": "Code1" 
            }]
        }
    },
    "bar": {
        "ItemDimension2": {
            "Item": "item2",
             "ItemIndex": 3,
            "SelectedItems": [{

                "Code": "code2" 
            }]
        },
        "ItemDimension3": {
            "Item": "item3",
            "ItemIndex": 2,
            "SelectedItems": [{

                "Code": "Code3" 
            }]
        }
    },
    "Lorem": {
        "ItemDimension4": {
           "Item": "item4",
            "ItemIndex": 5,
            "SelectedItems": [{

                "Code": "Code4" 
            }]
        }
    }
  };
```

I want to show this in view like

item1 - 1

item3 - 2

item2 - 3

item4 - 5

but it is showing like

item4 - 5

item2 - 3

item3 - 2

item1 - 1

in view template

```
<label ng-repeat="(catagory, items) in _Json">
          <li ng-repeat="(name, itemslist) in items | orderBy:'itemslist.ItemIndex'">

              <strong>{{itemslist.Item }}</strong> - <strong>{{itemslist.ItemIndex }}</strong> 

            </li>
       </label>
```

how to order this with ItemIndex ?

is this a proper method ? or do i want to change something?

with respect to [Angularjs OrderBy on ng-repeat doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920028/angularjs-orderby-on-ng-repeat-doesnt-work?answertab=active#tab-top) i have tried orderByobject but didnt wrk

check this Plunker source

http://plnkr.co/edit/UCnrGJjLLaEjP7K5geV0?p=preview

Comment: Did you try `:reverse` in the `orderBy` filter?

Comment: @Brett i have tried , but didnt work! Please check this plunker link
http://plnkr.co/edit/UCnrGJjLLaEjP7K5geV0?p=preview

Comment: Your Plunker example doesn't run for me at all.

Comment: @Brett working for me. 

item4 - 5
item2 - 3
item3 - 2
item1 - 1

as result

Comment: Your JSON data isn't an array, yet, you are treating it like one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parameter of `ng-repeat` to be actuall array in order for built in orderBy to work. See this question: [sorting values of a hash object in ngRepeat - angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552387/sorting-values-of-a-hash-object-in-ngrepeat-angularjs)

I would plugin underscore.js ( or lodash) and convert your data upfront.

See your updated fiddle http://plnkr.co/edit/odMCOp65zbyfbEfmU3FX?p=preview

add mapping to your controller (note, this is top level for simplicity, reference to updated fiddle for two level mapping)

```
$scope._Json = _.map($scope._Json, function( v, k) { 
    return { key: k, value: v}      
})
```

and change markup to (again, only top level here for simplicity, reference to updated plnkr for two level update):

```
<label ng-repeat="cat in _Json">
      <li ng-repeat="(name, itemslist) in cat.value | orderBy:'itemslist.ItemIndex'">        
          <strong>{{itemslist.Item }}</strong> - <strong>{{itemslist.ItemIndex }}</strong>               
      </li>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
<label ng-repeat="(catagory, items) in _Json">
   <li ng-repeat="(name, itemslist) in items | orderBy:'itemslist.ItemIndex':true">
      <strong>{{itemslist.Item }}</strong> - <strong>{{itemslist.ItemIndex }}</strong> 
   </li>
</label>
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: My bad, I didn't pay attention. You should check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920028/angularjs-orderby-on-ng-repeat-doesnt-work or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478106/angularjs-sorting-by-property or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387552/angular-cant-make-ng-repeat-orderby-work , you should be able to make it work.