# how to access nested json element in angular js

Tags: angularjs, json, api, multidimensional-array

**I want to display seeds or any other data present in "torrents" in html using angular **

This code works fine but when i try to display seeds it displays nothing.

**HTML CODE**

```
 <section class="list">
   <article ng-repeat="object in yifito"> 
    <a href="{{object.url}}" target="_system" onclick="window.open('{{object.url}}',_system,'location=yes')" class="item">
      <img ng-src="{{object.small_cover_image}}">
     <h2 class="noWhiteSpace">{{object.title}}</h2>
     <p class="noWhiteSpace">{{object.genres}}</p>
     <p class="noWhiteSpace">Year {{object.year}} Rating {{object.rating}}</p>
    <p class="noWhiteSpace">{{object.movies.seeds}}</p>


     </a>
   </article>
    </section>
```

**angular Code**

```
var app = angular.module('browser', ['ionic']);

app.controller('controller',function($scope,$http){

$scope.br =[]owse;
  $http({
method: "GET",
url: 

 })
  .then(function(toData){
   $scope.to= toData.data.data.movies;
    console.log(data);
  })



})
```

[1]:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to order data in ng-repeat with nested objects as JSON data in angular js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164001/how-to-order-data-in-ng-repeat-with-nested-objects-as-json-data-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `seeds` field is inside `torrents`. The field `torrents` is a list.
So, to display data from `torrents`, you must use a loop.

```
<article ng-repeat="object in yifito"> 
    <a href="{{object.url}}" target="_system" onclick="window.open('{{object.url}}',_system,'location=yes')" class="item">
        <img ng-src="{{object.small_cover_image}}">
        <h2 class="noWhiteSpace">{{object.title}}</h2>
        <p class="noWhiteSpace">{{object.genres}}</p>
        <p class="noWhiteSpace">Year {{object.year}} Rating {{object.rating}}</p>
        <div ng-repeat="torrent in object.torrents">
            <p class="noWhiteSpace">{{torrent.seeds}}</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</article>
```

It will display seeds for each torrent of your movie.

Comment: Sorry avantika i have tried that but its not working.

Comment: What do you mean "how" ?

Comment: I did, it's the <div ng-repeat"torrent... in my response. It will loop over each torrent and display its number of seeds

Answer (score 0):

Simply access `seeds` by modifiying your code to :

```
<p class="noWhiteSpace">{{object.seeds}}</p>
```

This is because the structure of your object `$scope.yifito` is as follows:

```
[
{title: abc,
 genere: afsdf,
 year: 2016,
 rating: 8,
 seeds: 234},
{...}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- `seeds` property is inside the object of a `torrent` array.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope,$http){

$scope.yifito =[];
  $http({
method: "GET",
url: "https://yts.ag/api/v2/list_movies.json?limit=50"

 })
  .then(function(yifitoData){
   $scope.yifito = yifitoData.data.data.movies;
    console.log($scope.yifito);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="object in yifito"> 
    <a href="{{object.url}}" target="_system" onclick="window.open('{{object.url}}',_system,'location=yes')" class="item">
     <img ng-src="{{object.small_cover_image}}">
     <h2 class="noWhiteSpace">{{object.title}}</h2>
     <p class="noWhiteSpace">{{object.genres}}</p>
     <p class="noWhiteSpace">Year {{object.year}} Rating {{object.rating}</p>
     <div ng-repeat="item in object.torrents">
        <p class="noWhiteSpace">{{item.seeds}}</p>
     </div>
     </a>
</div>
</div>
```